# Use of Switch Statement in Instance creation

Tags: c#

I came across the following code, which is creating an instance of base class (`AbstractClassType`):

```
AbstractClassType myVariable = someClassTypeArg.anotherClassTypeVar.EnumTypeVariable switch
{
    AnotherEnumType.enum1 => new DerivedClass_1_FromAbstractClassType(),
    AnotherEnumType.enum2 => new DerivedClass_2_FromAbstractClassType(),
    _ => throw new Exception("The provided enum is not valid"),
};
var computeThisVariable = myVariable.GetKeyData(something, anotherThing);
```

I am quite confused with the above code. Why the `Switch` statement is used (which C# concept is it...)?

Comment: This isn't a switch *statement* - it's a switch *expression*, introduced in C# 8. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression

Comment: *"creating an instance of base class"* - Probably not. If the name is any indication, that class is `abstract` so it can't be instantiated. What this is doing is instantiating one of the *derived* classes and returning a base class reference.

Comment: The switch expression is used to determine whether `DerivedClass_1_FromAbstractClassType` or `DerivedClass_2_FromAbstractClassType` has to be created based on an enum value.

Comment: @madreflection: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, the abstract class cannot be instantiated. I chose wrong selection of words ;)

Comment: @madreflection: Right. Just wondering, what should we call `AbstractClassType myVariable`? Is the variable `myVariable` an instance of `AbstractClassType` or an instance of the `DerivedClass`? If I say that `myVariable` is an instance of the class `DerivedClass`, wouldn't it be misleading too?

Comment: "AbstractClassType reference". That's as specific as you should get at that point. That's the point of polymorphism. The actual type is of no importance because you're using (what I assume is) the virtual surface area of the base class (e.g. `GetKeyData`). It's not misleading if the specifics of the implementation are intended to be hidden by polymorphism. To paraphrase my C++ instructor, you're "wearing AbstractClassType-colored glasses".

Comment: @madreflection: Wonderful clarification. Sorry, one more question, what is difference between `reference` and `instance`? And, isn't the `reference` in this case pointing to the derived class's object?

Comment: You are an instance. Your name is a reference. Your job title is a reference to you and how you perform your job, which is a mere slice of who you are and what you can do. Referring to you as a `Human` means that we can interact with the part of you that is a human without knowing the specifics of who **skm** is.

Comment: *"And, isn't the reference in this case pointing to the derived class's object?"* Yes (although that wording implies things about the derived class that you may not realize -- that may be caused by the way adjectives are applied in English). Let me put this another way: if you're looking through a spyglass, do you really care about the rest of the ocean, or just the land you've been seeking? A base-class reference is necessarily myopic.

Comment: @madreflection: Nice analogies. Thanks :)